# Decoding JSON containing unicode characters with Jackson

Tags: java, json, unicode, jackson

I am using Jackson to parse JSON responses coming from a web service (requests made with Spring RestTemplate).
The problem is the JSON contains unicode characters like \u00a0 or \u2212 or \ufeff, and those characters are "decoded" as question marks or �

First question, is it ok or bad practice for a web service to return such unicode characters in JSON responses? 
Should the response header Content-Type also contain "charset=utf-8" or "application/json" is enough?

Second question, how to make Jackson able to decode those characters?
Here is a test:

```
String json = "{\"message\":\"Text containing unicode like \\u00a0 or \\u2212 or \\ufeff\"}";
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
    JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json);
    JsonNode jnode = mapper.readTree(parser);
    String message = jnode.get("message").toString();
    logger.info(message);
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And what I see in the console and in the logs:

"Text containing unicode like   or ? or ?"

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably saving the logs with the wrong encoding.

Comment: If you set the JVM default encoding to Unicode, you should be able to see the unicode symbols.

Comment: The thing is if I do logger.info(json) or System.out.println(json), it prints {"message":"Text containing unicode like \u00a0 or \u2212 or \ufeff"} which is correct so I guess there is a problem with Jackson.

Comment: @MaximeLaval, Were you able to resolve this problem? I am stuck in a similar situation. Doing some research figured out that, UniCodes are divided into two categories, Control Codes & Latin Codes. It looks like JsonNode.get("attribute") handles control codes to return Unicode correctly, however, if the value of the attribute falls in the Latin codes category, it interprets the corresponding ASCII character. Any help is appreciated.      Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters.